# Swift: didSelectContactProperty Isn't Called

Tags: ios, swift, delegates, contacts, cncontact

I've realized that **if I use the delegate method `contactPicker:didSelectContact` to present a custom `CNContactViewController`, the method `contactPicker:didSelectContactProperty` is no longer called.**

```
func openPicker() {
    let picker = CNContactPickerViewController()
    picker.delegate = self
    self.presentViewController(picker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}

func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContact contact: CNContact) { 
    //contactPicker:didSelectContactProperty works when this method is commented out

    let controller = CNContactViewController(forContact: contact)
    controller.delegate = self
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(controller, animated: true)
}

func contactViewController(viewController: CNContactViewController, shouldPerformDefaultActionForContactProperty property: CNContactProperty) -> Bool {

    return false
}

func contactPicker(picker: CNContactPickerViewController, didSelectContactProperty contactProperty: CNContactProperty) {

    print("selected contact property")
}
```

*How can I present a custom `CNContactViewController` **and** be notified when a user selects a property?*

Using `contactViewController:shouldPerformDefaultActionForContactProperty` to record the selected data does work, but it seems like an abuse of that method.

Comment: I did not manage to get both methods to get triggered, but I noticed one can access the **CNContact** from the `didSelectContactProperty` method : `contactProperty.contact`